# PHP Based Web Crawler or JAVA Based Web Crawler

Tags: java, php, web-crawler

i have some doubt about PHP based web crawlers,can it run like the java thread based one? i am asking it because, in java the thread can be executed again and again, i dont think, PHP have something like thread function, can you guys please say, which web crawler will be more use full?A PHP Based or A Java Based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing your own use one of the following. Btw, Java based web crawlers are preferred. My fav Nutch.

Java based: [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/), Heritrix, JSpider, JoBo (simple crawler)

PHP based: PHPCrawl

Comment: Which is Good??Java based or PHP Based?

Comment: Java based! Use Nutch it comes with Lucene.

Comment: Nutch does web-crawling (following and downloading links) stuff only. Lucene is an indexing engine and builds a `inverted index` of documents. Don't worry abt Lucene, Nutch takes care of it. (vote up if it works for you :P )

Comment: i dont have enough point to vote up :(

Answer (score 0):

In general, you will need to jump through more hoops to run long-running tasks in PHP, as it's much more of an request/response-based setup.